# How to show streaming videos in flash in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, flash, streaming

I want to show live video streaming which is in the form of flash. Can any body tell me how to do this in an iPhone application.

Thanks

Ashwani

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone doesn't support Flash, so using it isn't an option. You can, however, do HTTP streaming of video. Read [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe announced during their Keynote at MAX yesterday that you will be able to compile Flash for iPhone apps. They have some sample projects available on the [Adobe labs site](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashcs5/appsfor_iphone/)

You can take those sample files and extend them to accomplish what you're looking for.

The native compile output from Flash Professional isn't going to be available until CS5.

Note: Flash is not native on the iPhone and will not run in browser. Also, apps will not have access to the video camera or the microphone.

Comment: compiled streaming video!? sweet

Comment: Thanks, I will see those applications

Comment: @qntmfred yeah, compiled streaming video would be a neat trick! I bet Jon Skeet could pull it off! ;)

Answer (score 0):

No flash but you can stream mp4 etc.

good tutorial on how to stream video:

http://buildmobilesoftware.com/2010/08/09/how-to-stream-videos-on-the-iphone-or-ipad/